# PHP - some proplems on detecting HTTPS Protocol

Tags: php, jquery

i am getting an problem on loading my Template and i had tried testing my template on XAMPP and the same problem happened again

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@main-hosting.eu to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.`

it doesn't show anything at first just loading page and then that error no more... please help but on XAMPP it just keeps loading my page
but after some time when i was trying to resolve the problem, found it and tried solving it but i need some help please on fixing the code which caused it before

```
$Domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$Path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];   
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) 
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("https://' .$Domain.$Path. '");</script>';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("http://' .$Domain.$Path. '");</script>';
}
```

please some help ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because each time your page is loading the script is running and refreshing the site endless. You need to know if the page have already been redirected.
example:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['r'])){
        $Domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $Path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];   
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) 
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("https://' .$Domain.$Path. '?r=https");</script>';
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("http://' .$Domain.$Path. '?r=http");</script>';
        }
    }
 ?>
```

I do not understand the point of this.. And I would recommend you to use Location instead. Example:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very poor way to reload a page. 
The code below reloads the page infinitely until the url is modified...
To understand this, run the code below...

$Domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
   $Path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {

```
    echo 'HTTPS AVAILABLE';
    echo '<script type=   "text/javascript">window.location.assign("https://' . $Domain .$Path. '");</script>';
} else { 



echo 'HTTPS NOT AVAILABLE  ';   
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("http://' .   $Domain .$Path.' ");</script>';
```

}

while the pages keeps loading, modify the code to this

```
$Domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$Path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {

```
echo 'HTTPS AVAILABLE';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("https://' .   $Domain . '");</script>';
```

} else {

```
echo 'HTTPS NOT AVAILABLE  ';   
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("http://' .  $Domain .' ");</script>';
```

}

once saved this will redirect you to https://localhost or http://localhost
if running on your local machine.

The window.location.assign() reloads the page infinitely if the url is the same.

Comment: its bad idea to keep the browser on the main index template every time and then it will keep reloading the page just no more if you aren't checking logging something on code running and check for it before it get ran as @ChristianG's Reply (tested).... Internal Server ERROR as my original Proplem.